# Adding new field on invoice_line_ids in account.move (odoo 13)

Tags: python, odoo-13

I faced a problem while adding a new field to invoice_line_ids field in account.move
Actually, the field has been added but it is not saving the value whenever I create a new invoice or edit an invoice.

I tried this, but It is still not saving!!
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/40915#issuecomment-574624912

this is my code:

```
class account_move_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move.line"
    
    detail_ids = fields.One2many(string="Details",
                         comodel_name="account.move.line.detail", 
                         inverse_name="line_id")
    
class account_move_line_detail(models.Model):
    _name = "account.move.line.detail"
    
    line_id = fields.Many2one(string="Line", comodel_name="account.move.line", ondelete="cascade")
    value = fields.Char(string="Value")

<record id='account_view_move_form' model='ir.ui.view'>
    <field name='name'>account.view.move.form</field>
    <field name='model'>account.move</field>
    <field name='inherit_id' ref='account.view_move_form' />
    <field name='arch' type='xml'>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_line_ids']/form//field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <field name="detail_ids">
                <tree editable="bottom">
                    <field name="value"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </xpath>
        
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='line_ids']/form/group" position="inside">
            <field name="detail_ids" invisible="1"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It would be better if you show code for update or create And also the field definition.

Comment: ok, i have updated the code, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Please define the field you have added newly to account move line in 'line_ids' o2m tree view.

That is inherit the account move form view and in the line_ids tree view inside the form view please define your new field as invisible

Comment: Hi anitha, i have already set your recommendation but the problem persist, thanks for you response!!!

Comment: Could you please try to give the field in tree view also as invisible

Answer (score 0):

use attribute force_save="1" in your field attribute in xml like this for example.
 then your field will save data in account.move.line

Comment: hi Syed, thanks for your answer, I understand that the option force_save = "1" is used to save a field (readonly) calculated using @api.onchange, I have tried applying this option in both fields "detail_ids" and "value", but still not working